# How to convert csv to pdf in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I need to convert csv data to a PDF file. Using iText I have written this code:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pdfFile));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4.Rotate());

PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD);

iText.Layout.Element.Table table = new iText.Layout.Element.Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(new float[] { 14, 6, 12, 16, 12, 12, 12, 12, 6 }));
using (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(excelFile)))
{
    String line = br.readLine();


    addRowToTable(table, line, bold, true);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        addRowToTable(table, line, font, false);
    }
}

doc.Add(table);

doc.Close();
```

and

```
    public void addRowToTable(iText.Layout.Element.Table table, String line, PdfFont font, Boolean isHeader)
    {


        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

        // Creates cells according to parsed csv line
    while (tokenizer.HasMoreTokens())
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(tokenizer.NextToken(",")+"\r\n").SetFont(font));

            if (isHeader)
            {
                table.AddHeaderCell(cell);
            }
            else
            {
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the output of each entry is not to new line, instead it appends directly to the previous one, in the same row, as the screen shot illustrates:

[image]

The original file, opened as a spreadsheet, looks like this

[image]

The required output:

[image]

Comment: Can i check the no of tqble on run time??

Comment: Improved grammar for better readability, inserted images

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a table with 9 columns:

```
new iText.Layout.Element.Table(
    UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(
        new float[] { 14, 6, 12, 16, 12, 12, 12, 12, 6 }
    )
);
```

That's why you see the unexpected behavior.

Create a table with 4 columns:

```
new iText.Layout.Element.Table(
    UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(
        new float[] { 35, 15, 25, 25 }
    )
);
```

Comment: can i check table column on runtime

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by that? I did not get it. Can you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: i want to say if i have another file with 15 column than how can I manage this I cannot change the value everytime at background I want a proper solution if I will convert any number of column it  convert properly please help

Comment: You can get the number of header fields in the csv file. You don't give the full context of your problem so this only solves what you gave so far.